# Google Analytics showing (not set) when viewing by Page Title

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, googlebot

I'm trying to figure out why there is a row that shows a page title as (not set) in the `Site Content > All Pages > Page Title` table.

I've read that this issue can be caused by improperly set page titles, but the URI points to the main directory of our site: `/`, and there is no problem with the page title in the HTML.

Anyone had this problem before?

Edit: Still trying to figure this out. I notice that the row with (not set) is not in the list when viewing by Page because its URI is the same as the landing page to the site, which is `/`. Still could use some real assistance on this though, not too familiar with SEO.

Edit 2: I'm using `<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>` in the head of my root web directory `/`. Could this be a factor?

Comment: `noodp` should prevent Google from showing a description taken from dmoz.org in the search results in place of your meta description.   I can't imagine it would affect anything in Google Analytics, especially not page titles.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with analytics spam.

In GA properties ending in 1 (e.g. UA-XXXXXXX-1) there's a huge problem with "ghost spam" this is when spammers ping GA servers directly and never even visit your site. At first it was mostly reporting fake sources of referral traffic but I've seen fake events being sent as well (and even visits to non-existent URLs).

Nearly every site has `/` as a page so that's a good one to report if faking data.

That'd be my guess but if your site uses virtual pages in GA for tracking purposes, it's possible that could be misconfigured.

I could think of other possible explanations too but I think those 2 are most likely.